# Annotation based string validation

Tags: java, string

Is there a library which allows to do AOP based string validation in Java. Something like this:

```
@StringValidate("some_regex_pattern")
String sample;
```

and preferably at compile time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at any of the [JSR-303 implementations](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) or the [https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVAEE_SPEC-20 6 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html)?

You'd want the `@Pattern` annotation.

I don't understand the "at compile time", since that seems a bit useless, and wouldn't really be AOP IMO which is usually a runtime, byte-code manipulation thing. There's SpringContracts, which is obviously Spring, and a few AspectJ-based libraries (although it's not that difficult to roll your own).

Comment: Thanks Dave, the reason I asked for compile time validation, is because of the nature of my checks. I have a lot of fields with known format patterns like emails,postcodes. So what I wanted to have is some kind of annotation on the setter which would generate the certain validation code at compile time. This way I expect to avoid lots of boilerplate validation.

Comment: @husayt Well, the AOP stuff can be woven at compile time, if that's what you meant.